# Load img in 3 input files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input with a class of `general` and three with `simple`.

```
<input type="file" class="general">
<input type="file" class="simple">
<input type="file" class="simple">
<input type="file" class="simple">
```

im want If user selects a file in `.general`, his load in other 3 input.
im need simulate 1 file load in 3(or more) input
Something like this

```
$(".general").change(function(){
$(".simple").trigger("change") //change and add file in simple
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by `his load in other 3 input`?  You can't "load" a file into input. Do you mean that you want to display the file (image?) that you uploaded?

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to allow the user to see the 3 "simple" inputs if they have already interacted with the "general" input?

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to allow the user to see the 3 "simple" inputs if they have already interacted with the "general" input?
yes im want if user load 1 image in general input, this image load in other 3 input

Comment: Can you explain why you need 3 uploads from the same file? Maybe are better solution for your attempt.

Comment: im load image into 1 input, and im need what image load in 3 input

Comment: Do you need the same image will "load" into the other 3 inputs?

Comment: yes im refresh questions, and add pseudocode

Comment: Well, you can't "load" file into input. Why do you need to "load" the file to other inputs? Can you explain us the big picture?

Comment: file must upload in 3 input automatical,without dialog window

Comment: You can't do this.. and I didn't understood do you need such a bizarre behavior..

Comment: im want load 1 picure and crop this for 3 different proportions

Comment: You can't just load a file into an `input` element - Why do you need to do this?

Comment: how i can do this?

Comment: You can use a plugin for this https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

Comment: Now you are talking ;) You can use a plugin such as http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

Comment: im use plugin http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/
but his working with 1 input

Comment: fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper 
how i can download file in slient side?how get base64 image?

Comment: This look like a very basic plugin, try what me and @MoshFeu suggested

Comment: im try but can i save cropped image on client side?

Comment: @Nikolay We can't spoon feeding you. You'll have to read the documentation and figure it out yourself, but it is possible.

Comment: And if you will a **specific** question we will be happy to answer and help..

Comment: im not understand how save cropped image without php

Comment: If you want to let the user to crop his image then download it, you can use `canvas`. If not, what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need to dynamically set value of a file input.

But it is not possible to dynamically change the value of a file field. Because you could set it to `"c:\path\to\a\file"` and steal files very easily.